# Beginner: Using a void function to calculate carpet cost in Python?

Tags: python, void

Here are what the instructions for this assignment say:

Write a program named carpet.py that uses a void function named carpet_cost to calculate and display the cost of carpeting a rectangular room. The function should take the length of the room in feet, width of the room in feet, and the cost of carpet per square yard as arguments. These three values should be obtained from user inputs in the main function. The carpet_cost function should calculate and display the cost of the carpet in currency format with a $ sign right up against the first digit, a comma separator if the amount is in the thousands, and two decimal places.

Here's what I have so far,

```
length = int(input("What is the length of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: "))
width = int(input("What is the width of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: "))
cost = int(input("What is the cost per square yard of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: "))

def carpet_cost(total_cost):

    total_cost == ((length * width) / 3) * cost

    print('The cost to carpet this room will be $', format(total_cost, ',.2f'))

carpet_cost(total_cost)
```

I am having trouble with how to make it into void function and I have tried to look everywhere but I haven't found a way to make it so. I do know how to calculate it using simpler methods by using only one function but am really confused about how void functions can help provide the same output.

Any help would be appreciated and sorry if my code is bad but it's because I am having a hard time wrapping my head around void functions.

Comment: Quick question. What is a void function?

Comment: Well your carpet_cost function isn't returning anything, so I'd say that its a void

Comment: Python doesn't really *have* "void functions", so your specification is misleading (perhaps badly translated from some other language) - *every function* returns something, if you don't `return` anything explicit it's `None`.

Comment: Even if it returns `None`, I think `print` statement should be correctly formatted anyway.

Comment: @Kevin I don't know why my book calls it that, makes it more confusing if you ask me.

Comment: what book is this? you should probably just burn it now and be done with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "void" you mean "doesn't return anything", you already have a void function.

Your `carpet_cost` function takes one parameter `total_cost`, but instead it should take three parameters for length, width, and cost per square yard. Additionally, you should be using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality testing operator `==`.

```
length = int(input("What is the length of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: "))
width = int(input("What is the width of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: "))
cost = int(input("What is the cost per square yard of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: "))

def carpet_cost(l,w,c):
    total_cost = ((l * w) / 3) * c
    print('The cost to carpet this room will be $', format(total_cost, ',.2f'))

carpet_cost(length,width,cost)
```

Result:

```
What is the length of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: 3
What is the width of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: 3
What is the cost per square yard of tbe room you're trying to carpet?: 50
The cost to carpet this room will be $ 150.00
```

Also, you seem to have an arithmetic problem when calculating total cost. If you want to convert square feet into square yards, you have to divide by nine, not three.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Also in pycharm it was showing the error that total_cost had no other reference but when I typed your code in, the error went away somehow.

Oops, forgot about making that a 9, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

one of these surely might be what you want

```
#example 1
def carpet_cost(length,width,cost_per_unit):
    return length*width*cost_per_unit

print carpet_cost(length=5,width=10,cost_per_unit=2.10)

#example 1.0005 
def carpet_cost(length,width,cost_per_unit):
    print length*width*cost_per_unit


#example 2 (pass by reference, since a list is editable)
def carpet_cost(args_list):
    length,width,cost_per_unit = args_list
    args_list[:] = [length*width*cost_per_unit]

length,width,cost = 5,10,1.12
result = [length,width,cost] # a list is editable
carpet_cost(result)
print result
```

Answer (score -1):

See [Python void-like function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077528/python-void-like-function). Python is dynamically typed and it's functions will always return something. If you don't specify a return value, python automatically returns `None`.

Also, you have `total_cost` as an argument for `carpet_cost`, which is the function that calculates `total_cost`. I think you need to check your logic.